# Animate element switch with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

To get some experience with react-js I wanted to script a small slide-show that switches between some slides with fade animations. (I know - maybe there is the ultimate hyper-slideshow lib out there but to get into the topic I started this way :))

But somehow I got stuck with the animation part and was also wondering if a skilled react-js programmer would code it the way I started with.
Currently the slides are switching without the animation I've got from here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable

Here is my main file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'
import Slide from './Slide'
import '../styles/slider.css';

class Slider extends Component {

constructor() {
    super()
    this.slides = [
        {
            text: "I'm a dummy text #1",
            imgName: "./assets/img01.jpg"
        },
        {
            text: "I'm a dummy text #2",
            imgName: "./assets/img02.png"
        }
    ]

    this.state = {
        currentSlideIdx: 0
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.shiftSlide()
}

shiftSlide () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            currentSlideIdx: this.state.currentSlideIdx < this.slides.length - 1 ? this.state.currentSlideIdx + 1 : 0
        })
        this.shiftSlide()
    }, 2000)
}

render() {

    const slide = <Slide key={this.slides[this.state.currentSlideIdx]} meta={this.slides[this.state.currentSlideIdx]} />

    return (
        <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="example"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
            {slide} 
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
   )
}
}

export default Slider
```

and the slider.css contains the example styles:

```
.example-enter {
opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
opacity: 0.01;
transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}
```

I'd be happy if someone could give me a hint what would be the best way to proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable#high-level-api-csstransitiongroup):

> CSSTransitionGroup is a high-level API based on TransitionGroup and is
>   an easy way to perform CSS transitions and animations **when a React
>   component enters or leaves the DOM**

Your Slide component never leaves the DOM.
Which means you should make your animations *inside* `Slide` component.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I've moved the code inside my Slide component, but unfortunately the result is the same. It simply toggles the slides without animation...